# C++ Constructor called from function by reference

Tags: c++

I was doing some C++ test and I don't understand the code below:

```
class A
{
public:
A(int n = 0): m_n(n)
{
    std::cout << 'd';
}

A(const A& a): m_n(a.m_n)
{
    std::cout << 'c';
}

private:
    int m_n;
};

void f(const A &a1)
{
}

int main()
{
    //Call 'f' function and prints: d
    f(3);
    return 0;
}
```

What I don't understand is why the constructor is called here and prints 'd'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing an `int` value to a function that wants a reference to an `A` value. In order to provide that argument, a temporary `A` is created using the conversion constructor `A(int)`, printing `'d'`.

The temporary is destroyed at the end of the expression statement, after the function returns.

Note that this only work if the reference is either `const`, or an *rvalue* reference. Temporary values can't bind to non-const *lvalue* references; so, if the argument type were `A&`, then you should get an error.

It also requires that the conversion can be done implicitly; you could prevent this conversion by declaring the constructor `explicit`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour or just [**linking it**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean)

Answer (score 2):

```
A(int n = 0): m_n(n)
{
    std::cout << 'd';
}
```

This is a conversion constructor. When the function needs a parameter of type `A` but a `int` variable is supplied, it'll be ***implicitly converted*** to `A` using this conversion constructor.

To avoid this implicit conversion, you can add `explicit` specifier to your constructor.

```
explicit A(int n = 0): m_n(n)
{
    std::cout << 'd';
}
```